# jquery to apply css on the first table row of every table

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to apply different style to **every** first table row below a certain class using this code:

```
$(".my-class tr:first td").css({"color":"#0064CC","font-size":"15px","border-bottom-style":"none"});
```

The problem is that it only applies it to the **first** table it finds below that class.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
$(".my-class tr:first td").each(function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"#0064CC","font-size":"15px","border-bottom-style":"none"});
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following :

```
$(".my-class").find("tr:first td").css({"color":"#0064CC","font-size":"15px","border-bottom-style":"none"});
```

Your previous code was only finding the first row and td, this will find every element with `.my-class` and find the first tr/td element of the found elements.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of the table you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try for precision

```
$(".my-class").find("tr td:eq(0)").css({"color":"#0064CC","font-size":"15px","border-bottom-style":"none"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 $(".my-class tr:first td")
```

to

```
$("table tr:first").has('.my-class').find('td')
```